# update password protected linked word document in C#

Tags: c#, excel, linked-list, ms-word, password-protection

Let me first describe the problem. I have this application that opens a word document and updates all the fields and then saves the document in another folder. The word document is just used as a template for a report. It is filled with linked content from an excel worksheet. The whole application works, but the problem is that the excel document is password protected. when I update the document fields the application is stopped and word asks for a password.

When you input the password, the program works as advertised, you have to insert it more than once thou, dont really know why. But the program is suppose to work autonomously without user input. Is there a way to give word the password so that it doesnt have to be entered, either via code or in the word document properties.

Below is my current code that does this, its in C#

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(template, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
        doc.Activate();
        red_debug.AppendText("opening " + template + "\n");
        doc.Fields.UpdateSource();
        doc.Fields.Update();
        red_debug.AppendText("Saving as " + final + "\n");
        doc.SaveAs(final, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument);
        doc.SaveAs(path + "\\" + name, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
        red_debug.AppendText("Closing word" + "\n");
        doc.Close();
        ap.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Word document to open up the Excel file (with the password) for you everytime it has been opened. Same time, we can also successfully close the Excel file from Word.

Put this into the Word macro area.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim myRange

Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelFile.xls", , , , "password", "password")
Set myRange = Selection.Range

    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.Update
    myRange.Select

xlApp.Quit
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll

End Sub
```

*This will open up the excel document and update ALL fields on your word document and shouldnt ask you for password*

Comment: How do I add this to word macro? Sorry I have absolutely no experience with word macro or visual basic for that matter.

Comment: @blackwolfsa Open your Word document that you use part of your programme. Then, 'alt-F11' int VBA. On the left, expand your document name, and double click "This Document". Paste the above in there and save and exit.

Comment: Still ask for the password if I update it. I changed the password to excel part to the correct password.

Comment: What happens if you open the word document through the normal desktop way and update your fields?

Comment: Please try the new Word VBA code i have just edited on my answer. This will open up the excel document and update ALL fields on your word document and shouldnt ask you for password

Comment: Thanks that works, but it there a way to keep excel from asking if I want to save the excel file?

Comment: Add `xlWB.Close savechanges = False` above `XlApp.quit`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to call `doc.Unprotect(ref Object password)` by passing your password as argument.

Check out  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39159/Bulk-Office-Protection-Application) article on CodeProject and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.unprotect.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: document.unprotect is to remove the password on a document. The document the application opens does not have a password. The excel document that contains the graphs is. When I open it, excel asks for the password when word asks for the updated info